# Does SDR configured with low sample rate automatically averages samples?

Tags: sampling, downsampling, software-defined-radio

This is probably a basic question but I didn't find any answer online.

Suppose we configure a SDR (least say, with a maximum sample rate of 100 Msamples/s) with a low sample rate (e.g. 1 Msample/s).

- Does the SDR actually samples at 1Msample/s and sends only that  (e.g. to GNU-radio)?
- Or does the SDR sample at 100Msamples/s and decimates and then sends the decimated 1Msample/s?
- Or does this depend on the SDR? If this is the case, are there examples of SDRs that do the 1st or 2nd option

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SDR and ADC is designed to sample at 100 MHz, then the analog anti-alias filter of properly designed is also wide enough for most of that bandwidth up to Nyquist (or could use bandpass sampling to undersample a higher frequency band with a bandwidth at 85% of Nyquist or so).

That said, we would never want to configure the SDR to sample at 1 Ms/sec due to the significant noise elevation and interference due to aliasing. The OP is correct in the desire to sample at the highest rate and then decimate digitally to a lower rate.

This will be specific hardware and software capabilities (as to what the user can configure ) for the given SDR design. I recommend reading the manufacturers datasheet and contacting them about such possible configurations. There is nothing about a generic “SDR implementation” that would preclude the ability to do this, but the initial point I made about ensuring the signal is sampled at the rate consistent with the analog anti-alias filter would always hold (unless you want to make such hardware changes to the board).